# How do I use collection_check_boxes with an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, simple-form

So I'm using simple_form for building my forms, this is not a requirement though.

What I am trying to do is using simple_forms collection_check_boxes and pass it an array.

I am storing my tags in configatron:

```
configatron.tags = [{:name => "wheels", :tagtype => "property"}, {:name => "roof", :tagtype => "property"}, {:name => "doors", :tagtype => "property"}]
```

Here is my Tag model:

```
class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :taggable, polymorphic: true

  field :name
  field :tagtype
end
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :tags, @tags, @tags.map{|tag| tag.name}, @tags.map{|tag| tag.name} %>
```

where `@tags` is set to `configatron.tags` in controller

I simply want to make the collection_check_boxes work and then on before_save build the tag and embed it in the current resource.

I've read somewhere that you can map into the collection passed in and pick the content of an item of that collection. If i get it right, override the value_method?
Can't seem to remember how you can do this though. I also want to pass in the current tags of this resource `:collection => resource.tags`so that these tags is checked on rendering.

Is there any way of doing this? How would I manipulate the form_builder to make this possible, if so, how? Should I take another approach?

Sidenote: This functionality should work with backbone too, in some places backbone would be used for adding tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking [simple-form docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form),  I think you need to pass in the value_method and label_method as symbols to `collection_check_boxes`

Such as this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :tags, @tags, :name, :name %>
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 12):

How to use `collection_check_boxes` with an `Array`:

```
FRUITS = [[1, 'Abiu'], [2, 'Açaí'], [3, 'Assai'], [4, 'Acreola']]

<%= f.collection_check_boxes :fruits, FRUITS, :first, :last %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a one-dimensional Array just use `.to_s` to display just the value of each element:

```
FRUITS = ['Abiu', 'Açaí', 'Assai', 'Acreola']

<%= f.collection_check_boxes :fruits, FRUITS, :to_s, :to_s %>
```

Comment: this is one of the reasons why they loves dynamically typing